Remove Transfer-Hook from my token
I am thinking of methods to write a whitelist functions on a token. Is there a more efficient way to do this, as I want only specific wallets to be able to buy/send/transfer my tokens, I see that there is a way to do this via transfer hooks.
So I have like another yes/no question, after using the transfer-hook function to whitelist my token to specific wallets, is there a way to now cancel this function from off my token ?

Definitely! You just need to disable the transfer hook program id on your token. You can do that by running:
$ spl-token set-transfer-hook <TOKEN_MINT_ID> --disable

